# convergence of two mixed iteration formulas: $y_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} (y_k + z_k^{-1})$ and $z_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} (z_k + y_k^{-1})$

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Let $a>1$. We are given the following iterations: 
$$y_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} (y_k + z_k^{-1})$$ 
$$z_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} (z_k + y_k^{-1})$$ with $z_0 = 1$ and $y_0 = a$.

I need to show that $\{ y_k \}$ converges to $\sqrt{a}$ and $\{ z_k \}$ converges to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ and then find the rate of convergence of $\{ y_k \}$.

By working with both formulas I got to $\frac{y_{k+1}}{z_{k+1}} = \frac{y_{k}}{z_{k}}$, so if I denote that $t_k = \frac{y_{k}}{z_{k}}$ I will have $t_{k+1} = t_k$, meaning the iterations $t_{k+1} = g(t_k)$ where $g(t) = t$.

But then $g'(t) = 1$, and I can't use theorems about convergence.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well done to find  $y_k/z_k$ is constant.

By induction, $$\frac{y_k}{z_k}=\frac{y_0}{z_0}=a$$ so replace $z_k$ by $y_k/a$ in the first equation, and you have a single, simpler iteration.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve this. The rate of convergence is quadratic right?

Comment: Yes, i think it is.

Comment: Great! thanks again